# Web to Case SuppliedName not populating

Tags: case, html, web2lead, email2case

My Web to Case form is populating all data on the Case other than the Web Name (SuppliedName). Is there a way to populate the name? I assume everything should be the same formatting wise as the SuppliedEmail and SuppliedPhone.

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="name">Contact Name</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <input id="SuppliedName" name="name" placeholder="" class="slds-input" type="string" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

```
<form action="https://salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
<input type=hidden name="orgid" value="000000000000000">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="www.google.com">
<input type=hidden name="Created_From_Contact_Us__c" value="true">

<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="name">Contact Name</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <input id="SuppliedName" name="name" placeholder="" class="slds-input" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="email">Email</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <input id="SuppliedEmail" name="email" placeholder="" class="slds-input" type="email" value="" />
        </div>
</div><div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="phone">Phone</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <input id="SuppliedPhone" name="phone" placeholder="" class="slds-input" type="string" value="" />
        </div>
</div>
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="subject">Subject</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <input id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="" class="slds-input" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
</div><div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="description">Description</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <input id="description" name="description" placeholder="" class="slds-input" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="slds-button-group">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: The ID is irrelevant; that is only used by HTML, JavaScript, and CSS, but has no affect on data sent to the server. The important attribute is "name", which should be "name" (e.g. `name="name"`), which appears to be the case. My first thought would be that your input field is outside of the form element, which should be the main reason why the value wouldn't come over. To be certain, though, you'd want to check your "network" tab in the browser's developer console and manually inspect the request.

Comment: @sfdcfox it is inside of the form tags and when I inspect everything looks sound. I updated the post with the full html. I have a feeling it has something to do with Contact being a look up and somehow the SuppliedName is linked to Contact or the data type of "string" vs "text". I am not entirely sure, just take shots in the dark

Comment: I created a custom field for the name and was able to update that field. There is something weird going on with the SuppliedName api name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those of you who are still bumping into this problem, I ran into this recently and ended up in a support case with Salesforce.

Salesforce R&D identified this problem as working "by design" even though this means their HTML generator is not compatible with Experience cloud. After some pushing, they revealed if you want this to work you need to use "first_name",
not "suppliedName" or "name" for the name parameter.

The support rep seemed a little embarrassed having to convey this message, but hey it worked...

I've updated OPs example HTML code, with the updated name parameter to help the next person who trips up on this thread.

```
<form action="https://salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
<input type=hidden name="orgid" value="000000000000000">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="www.google.com">
<input type=hidden name="Created_From_Contact_Us__c" value="true">

<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="name">Contact Name</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <input id="SuppliedName" name="first_name" placeholder="" class="slds-input" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="email">Email</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <input id="SuppliedEmail" name="email" placeholder="" class="slds-input" type="email" value="" />
        </div>
</div><div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="phone">Phone</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <input id="SuppliedPhone" name="phone" placeholder="" class="slds-input" type="string" value="" />
        </div>
</div>
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="subject">Subject</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <input id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="" class="slds-input" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
</div><div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="description">Description</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <input id="description" name="description" placeholder="" class="slds-input" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="slds-button-group">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting the form on a community page, it seems that it strips name="name" from the HTML - you can see this in Chrome if you right click and choose 'inspect'.

If you save your form as a standalone HTML file and open it in a browser, I suspect it will populate the Web Name just fine.